# Simple type error on parsing the result of getArgs

Tags: haskell

I'm trying a very simple argument parser patterned off [this example](https://lotz84.github.io/haskellbyexample/ex/command-line-arguments).
The first argument ought to be a double, the second ought to be an integer, and if they aren't both of those types, I'd like to use default arguments for both specified in the else.  Here's what I have:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> (Double, Integer)
parseArgs args = do
  if length(args) == 2 then do
    let v1 = read (args !! 0) :: Double
    let v2 = read (args !! 1) :: Integer
    return (v1, v2)
  else do
    let v1 = read ("0.5") :: Double 
    let v2 = read ("5") :: Integer
    return (v1, v2)
```

I understand there are more sophisticated ways to parse arguments with an optparse-inspired design using `Applicative`, but I'm not there yet.

Here's the error I get:

```
myscript.hs:186:5-31: error: …
    • Couldn't match type ‘(Double, Integer)’ with ‘Integer’
      Expected type: (Double, Integer)
        Actual type: (Double, (Double, Integer))
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: return (v1, v2)
```

I don't understand this.  Looking at the signature of [`getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs), I don't see anything weird that would suggest I can't get my int back, or that it should return `(Double,Integer)` rather than just `Integer`.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `return` is a function from `a -> m a`, where `m` is a monad; it’s not part of the `do` syntax. Just write `(v1, v2)` to get the value `(v1, v2)`.

Comment: Thanks.  I only added return because when I only had the let statements, the compiler told me the last line of a do block had to be an expression, and that allowed it to compile.  I understand this behavior better now based on the answers below.

Comment: Note that `read` throws an error (and crashes the program) when given strings it can't parse into the appropriate type. If you want to improve on that, I suggest using [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) from `Text.Read`, which gives out `Nothing` when it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me that you have some experience in the "*imperative*" world where `return` seems to be a keyword to return content from a function.

In Haskell however, the `return` statement is used to define/use monads. The same for the `do` block by the way. Your type `(Int,Double)` can be used as a monadic type (kudos to [@duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913695/haskell-simple-getargs-type-error/41913833?noredirect=1#comment71009073_41913833) for that). But in this context it does not look much like you want/have to use monads, because this looks like a simple function.

So you can solve the problem with:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> (Double, Integer)
parseArgs args =
  if length(args) == 2 then
    let v1 = read (args !! 0) :: Double
        v2 = read (args !! 1) :: Integer
    in (v1, v2)
  else
    let v1 = read ("0.5") :: Double 
        v2 = read ("5") :: Integer
    in (v1, v2)
```

So you use `in` to say that you use the `v1` and `v2`, etc. in an expression. Still it is not very "Haskell-ish". A better way to do this is using guards (drop the `if-else`):

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> (Double, Integer)
parseArgs args | length args == 2 =
                     let v1 = read (args !! 0) :: Double
                         v2 = read (args !! 1) :: Integer
                     in (v1, v2)
               | otherwise =
                     let v1 = read ("0.5") :: Double 
                         v2 = read ("5") :: Integer
                     in (v1, v2)
```

Finally I do not really see why you use all these `let` statements and specify the types anyway. You can simply rewrite it to:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> (Double, Integer)
parseArgs args | length args == 2 = (read (args !! 0), read (args !! 1))
               | otherwise = (read "0.5", read "5")
```

Now we are still not done. Because of `args` has length two, that means it has the shape `[a,b]`. We can use that pattern in the head:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> (Double, Integer)
parseArgs [a,b] = (read a, read b)
parseArgs _     = (read "0.5", read "5")
```

The advantage is that you do no longer need to use `(!!)` to get the *i*-th element: checking and matching is done concurrently so to speak.

A last improvement I propose is to omit the `read` in the second case: you can simply enter `0.5` and `5`:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> (Double, Integer)
parseArgs [a,b] = (read a, read b)
parseArgs _     = (0.5, 5)
```

Comment: There actually is a `Monoid a => Monad ((,) a)` instance for pairs, which works just like `Writer`. That explains the counterintuitve type error the OP got, with the "actual type" reported by GHC being a nested pair.

Comment: @duplode: ah that explains. Still it is counterintuitive to use monads here since this is a pure function. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed -- the OP definitely doesn't need a writer monad here.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `do` notation here since that is for handling some monadic type. You can just match on the input list:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> (Double, Integer)
parseArgs [d, i] = (read d, read i)
parseArgs _ = (0.5, 5)
```