# Profiling with ThreadScope with command line arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, threadscope

I understand from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/ThreadScope#Using_ThreadScope) that to use ThreadScope I need to compile with an eventlog and rtsoptions, eg "`-rtsopts -eventlog -threaded`"

I am using Stack, so my compilation call looks like:

```
$ stack ghc -- -O2 -funfolding-use-threshold=16 -optc-O3 -rtsopts -eventlog -threaded mycoolprogram.hs
```

Whereas normally, I do:

```
$ stack ghc -- -O2 -funfolding-use-threshold=16 -optc-O3 -threaded mycoolprogram.hs
```

This compiles fine.  However, my program takes 2 and only 2 positional arguments:

```
./mycoolprogram arg1 arg2
```

I'm trying to add the RTS options `+RTS -N2 -l`, like so:

```
./mycoolprogram arg1 arg2 -- +RTS -N2 -l
```

Or

```
./mycoolprogram +RTS -N2 -l -- arg1 arg2
```

How can I simultaneously run my program with arguments going into `System.Environment.getArgs` (like eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913695/simple-type-error-on-parsing-the-result-of-getargs)) and also include these profiling flags?

Comment: `./mycoolprogram arg1 arg2 +RTS -N2 -l ` or `./mycoolprogram +RTS -N2 -l -RTS arg1 arg2` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sjakobi said you can use the `+RTS ... -RTS other arguments` or `other arguments +RTS ...` forms but there is also the option to pass them in an environment variable `GHCRTS`:

```
GHCRTS='-N2 -l' ./mycoolprogram arg1 arg2
```

Lost of more info is available in the [GHC users guide](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/runtime_control.html#setting-rts-options).